# classify text or sentences two classes : positive or very positive python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am looking for a way to classify positive sentences or texts in 2 classes : positive class and very positive class .

With marchine learning approach

Do you have an idea ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using machine learning approach? Do you have a training dataset for positive and very positive classes? If so you can use Bayes classification.

Comment: With machine learning approach

Comment: @hshantanu yes I have a dataset

Answer (score 0):

That depends how hands-on you want to be. You could use the [Natural Language Toolkit](https://www.nltk.org/) for example, or [TextBlob](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/), which is a very easy package to use, and recommended for simple cases.

[This](http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html) page explains how the NLTK deals with things, and [this page](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html) should get you up and running with TextBlob.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using machine learning approach, I would suggest using 'from reverend.thomas import Bayes' as follows:

```
from reverend.thomas import Bayes
class = Bayes()
#Train your data by traversing 
with open('positive.txt', 'r') as f:
    line = f.read()
    class.train('positive', line)
with open('very_positive.txt', 'r') as f:
    line = f.read()
    class.train('very_positive', line)
for phrase in testing_data:
    c = class.guess(phrase)
    print phrase, '-->', c
```

Comment: thanks but I only have a database which contains positve label for all sentences

Comment: @LeafLeafword, in that case, you would need a dataset with very positive labels as well. Otherwise, I do not see how you can use a machine learning approach.

Comment: Another approach I can think of is having a list of positive and very positive words. If the word is in very positive list, classify it very positive. If it is in positive, classify as positive.

Comment: @ hshantanu thanks a lot , At the moment I am looking for matching words but I do not know if it will be efficient

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you do not have a dataset with very positive labels. You can use a combination of lists as follows (you would need to update the words in the lists based on your choices and the data):

```
positive = ['good', 'nice']
very_positive = ['great', 'amazing', 'brilliant']
if any(word in data for word in very_positive):
    print 'Very Positive!'
elif any(word in data for word in positive):
    print 'Positive!'
else:
    print "Can't Classify"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks again the thing is , it is not efficient this way , I have a data set of only positive sentences

Comment: @LeafLeafword I think you need to define your problem accurately. The above classification can work if you have only positive sentences.